# jQuery TagEdit by webworka adding items programmatically

Tags: jquery

https://github.com/webworka/Tagedit/ is the reference.

I am trying to simply add an item programmatically.

I am unsure how to do that - is there a function there that I'm missing? If not, do I have to add it myself?

The example demo is here: http://tagedit.webwork-albrecht.de/. The idea runs the same as how StackOverflow does their tags - when you type an item, it searches through an auto complete list and gives you some default values in a dropdown. You can create a custom element as well by clicking on the white space inside the pseudo-input box area. When you press Enter (the designated button to complete an addition to the entry), TagEdit.js runs isNew() and something else before adding it to the input list.

What I want to do is programmatically add new elements to the input list (while still retaining TagEdit.js' isNew() function to prevent duplication entries. So, essentially, input.tagedit_add('new item'); would follow the course to add a new tag to the input box.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to hack it myself to make it work.

```
this.addNew = function (value) {
        var oldValue = (typeof value != 'undefined' && value.length > 0);
        var checkAutocomplete = oldValue == true? false : true;
        // check if the Value ist new
        console.log(value);
        var isNewResult = isNew(value, checkAutocomplete);
        if(isNewResult[0] === true || (isNewResult[0] === false && typeof isNewResult[1] == 'string')) {
            console.log('NEW: ' + value);

            if(options.allowAdd == true) {
                // Make a new tag in front the input
                html = '<li class="tagedit-listelement tagedit-listelement-old">';
                html += '<span dir="'+options.direction+'">' + value + '</span>';
                var name = baseName + '[]';
                html += '<input type="hidden" name="'+name+'" value="'+value+'" />';
                html += '<a class="tagedit-close" title="'+options.texts.removeLinkTitle+'">x</a>';
                html += '</li>';

                $('.tagedit-listelement-new').before(html);
            }
        } else { console.log('NOT NEW: ' + value)}
    };
return this;
```